# FastReport FMX 2.0 gives an error "clCantRen" when component placed on form

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, fastreport

Whenever I put FastReport 2.0 FMX -> TfrxReport component on my FMX form (RAD Studio 10.2), I do get error message popup **"clCantRen"**

When run without debugging I do get following error
"[dcc32 Error] E2161 Error: RLINK32: Error opening file "C:\FireMonkey\MainFrm.fmx"

My library path are as follows

Win32:- C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReport FMX\LibD25
Win64:- C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReport FMX\LibD25x64

Even whenever I do tried to save project or close project, it don't allow me to do so by popping up error msg "clCantRen".

Only after I removed component TfrxReport from the fmx form it allow me to save and close.
Kindly anyone please let me know why I am getting error with TfrxReport component at FMX form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any help why it generally shows "clCantRen" error message ?

Comment: If you have an active `FastReport` license, I suggest to add a ticket on the [official support site](https://support.fast-report.com/users/sign_in).

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the component?

Comment: problem solved by combined measures like reinstall and creation of file from scratch again...thanks all for help

Comment: Then please either answer you own question with the solution... or delete it. Also, for the future, avoid overtagging the question... the "rad" tag explicitly states that it should not be used, and is quite useless here as the other three are the ones that catch the attention of users that might have been useful :)

Answer (score 3):

These kind of errors are most likely encountered when the components are incorrectly installed. A possible solution is to reinstall the components. If this does not solve the problem, you should go further and contact the vendor with a small example which can reproduce the issue.